# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ExtractedValuesURLBuilder.build(…) When I use <h:form> in my search results page

Tags: jsf-2, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ExtractedValuesURLBuilder.build(…)
When I use   in my search results  page

Here are my configuration details

web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
   <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
   <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Using Jars
prettyfaces-jsf2-3.1.0.jar
prettyfaces-core-3.3.2.jar

pretty-config.xml

```
<url-mapping id="mySearch-result">
    <pattern value="/#{mySearchMBean.addressId}/"/>
    <view-id value="/pages/mySearch-result.xhtml"/> 
    <action>#{mySearchMBean.doLookupForAddress}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

mySearch.xhtml

```
      <h:form>
            Search Address by id:<br />
            <h:inputText value="#{mySearchMBean.addressId}" /><br />
             <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit"  action="pretty:mySearch-result" inclueViewParams="true">
             </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

ManagedBean and action method

```
@ManagedBean(name="mySearchMBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MySearchMBean {
public String doLookupForAddress() {
        MySearchDAO dao = new MySearchDAO();
        adresss = dao.findAddressById(addressId);
         System.out.println("doLookupForAddres");
        return "mySearch-result";
    }
}
```

mySearch-result.xhtml

```
<h:form>
<p><b>ADDRESS ID:</b> ${mySearchMBean.adresss.addressId}</p>
<p><b>NAME:</b> ${mySearchMBean.adresss.name}</p>
<p><b>STREET:</b> ${mySearchMBean.adresss.street}</p>
<p><b>LOCATION:</b> ${mySearchMBean.adresss.location}</p>
<p><b>ZIP:</b> ${mySearchMBean.adresss.zip}</p>
<h:form>
```

If I use h:form in mySearch-results.xhtml page its thowing exception with the root cause as below

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ExtractedValuesURLBuilder.build(Lcom/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/config/mapping/UrlMapping;)Ljava/lang/String;
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.getActionURL(PrettyViewHandler.java:124)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getActionURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getActionURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)+
```

If I remove `<h:form>` from mySearch-result page its working fine.

I am New to the Prettyfaces,

Am I missing anything? Is my configuration and url mapping are correct?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing different PrettyFaces versions:

```
prettyfaces-jsf2-3.1.0.jar
prettyfaces-core-3.3.2.jar
```

Update both to 3.3.3 and everything will be fine.